# .NET performance new byte[] buffer for each operation

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, buffer

I am receiving bytes from a socket to a buffer. Right now, the buffer is a byte array field that's large enough to handle any message I expect.

```
    byte[] recvBuffer = new byte[10000];

    public void Receive1(int len)
    {                        
        client.Receive(recvBuffer, len, SocketFlags.None);
    }
```

I could make improvements to the "elegance" my design by creating a new buffer each time instead

```
    public void Receive2(int len)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[len];
        client.Receive(buffer);
    }
```

My question is: **would the latter lead to reduced performance?**

Here's my attempt at answering the question myself. Let me know if this looks reasonable. I made a test client/server setup on my local machine using this code

```
class SocketTester
{
    private const string IP = "127.0.0.1";
    private const int PORT = 1776; // how patriotic

    Socket serv = new Socket(
        AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
        SocketType.Stream,
        ProtocolType.Tcp);

    Socket client = new Socket(
        AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
        SocketType.Stream,
        ProtocolType.Tcp);

    public SocketTester()
    {
        Socket listener = new Socket(
                AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                SocketType.Stream,
                ProtocolType.Tcp);

        listener.SetSocketOption(
            SocketOptionLevel.Socket,
            SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress,
            true);

        listener.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IP), PORT));
        listener.Listen(1);

        listener.BeginAccept((IAsyncResult ar) =>
        {
            serv = listener.EndAccept(ar);
        }, null);            

        /* fill it with junk data (i don't care about the actual values) */
        for (int i = 0; i < sendBuffer.Length; i++)
        {
            sendBuffer[i] = (byte)i;
        }
    }

    public void Connect()
    {
        client.Connect(IP, PORT);
        if (!client.Connected)
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }

    byte[] sendBuffer = new byte[4096];
    public void StartSending()
    {
        /* This blocks at 670 sends if nothing is received.*/
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            int i = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                serv.Send(sendBuffer);
                i++;
            }
        });
    }


    byte[] recvBuffer = new byte[10000];

    public void Receive1(int len)
    {                        
        client.Receive(recvBuffer, len, SocketFlags.None);
    }

    public void Receive2(int len)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[len];
        client.Receive(buffer);
    }


    public void LoopReceive1(int tries, int len)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < tries; i++)
        {          
            Receive1(len);
        }
    }

    public void LoopReceive2(int tries, int len)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < tries; i++)
        {
            Receive2(len);
        }
    }
}
```

I then used the VS debugger to step over each line.

```
SocketTester s = new SocketTester();

s.Connect();

Thread.Sleep(100);

s.StartSending();

Thread.Sleep(100);

s.LoopReceive1(500, 4096);

s.LoopReceive2(500, 4096);
```

Both lines seem to execute between 3 and 5 ms with seemingly random variations. I manally moved the execution point back several times (so order shouldn't be an issue). This seems more than fast enough for my application and seems to indicate little to no significant difference.

Am I missing anything here? I'm not particularly familiar with memory management and optimization, nor how it's affected by creating new variables in .NET. If there's something I should read on this topic, I'd love a link :)

Comment: I would say this is a scenario when using `ArrayPool` can be beneficial.

Comment: Your first solution looks simple enough. Don't create many objects in a loop if possible, you put pressure on the GC.

Comment: @Charles, The loop was just to see if I get any noticeable lags.. In real life, this receive method would be called at a rate of maybe 5x per second with messages of anywhere from 10 to 30000 bytes. Does that sound managable for the GC, or would you give the same advice?

Comment: Don't worry about it, but if you have a solution that reuses the buffer safely then i'd go with that.